# Can you do conditional order_by/regroup in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model "status" with fields `project_id` and `timestamp`. `project_id` is sometimes null, if the status isn't associated with a project (more specifically, if the status happens before we know what project caused it).

I want to order an output table as follows:

- group statuses with the same `project_id` together
- don't group null `project_id`s together
- order these groups and singletons by the latest timestamp of each group/singleton

Can this be done? I can almost achieve it just by sorting by timestamp, then using regroup. That's "almost" right because one group of identical project_ids can be split up by intervening nulls.

I'm pretty sure it can be done in SQL (GROUP BY isnull(experiment_id, -id)), but does Django allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for aggregation in django, you are better off doing raw sql as it is way faster than the generated orm sql. [Raw sql Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could do that.